# Finding $\arccos(\sin x) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I find $\arccos(\sin x) $? I have found a formula which states that $\arccos (\sin x) =\frac{\pi}{2}-x-2n \pi$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z} $, but I don't know how to choose $n$ depending on $x$'s value.

Comment: Do you mean $$\arccos(\sin(x))$$?

Comment: I too think the same.

Comment: Draw a triangle with sides $x$, $1$ and $\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, the formula I found is now all right. How do I find $n$?

Comment: Hint: $arccosx$ has the the range $[0, π]$. This might help you.

Comment: @JoMath Choose a value of $n$ such that the value of RHS lies between $0$ and $π$

Comment: See https://www.rapidtables.com/math/trigonometry/arccos.html

Comment: @nmasanta That's the website where I found the formula, but I hadn't understood how to choose $k$.

Comment: Then you have to follow @Jose Carlos Santos

Comment: That is exactly what I did, his answer was extremely useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends upon the value of $x$. If $x\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$, $\arccos\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)=\frac\pi2-x$. If $x\in\left[\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right]$, $\arccos\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)=x-\frac\pi2$. And so on…

And, of course, you should keep in mind that it is a periodic function with period equal to $2\pi$. So, knowing which values it takes in $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right]$ is enough to know the whole function.

[image: plot of the function graph]

Comment: So basically I choose $n$ so that $\arccos(\sin x) $ takes  all the values between $0$ and $\pi$ as suggested by another user above?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.